# Open a new window through a Treewidget child in PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qtreewidget

I´ve been dealing these last days with a problem regarding enabling a treewidget child to perform actions as opening a new window for example by clicking on it.

I appreciate any help,

this is the code:

```
from typing import KeysView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys,os
from pyautogui import click, press
from os import path
import sqlite3 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from os import path
from PyQt5 import uic
import clientes





class Main(QMainWindow,FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(Main,self).__init__()
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.clientesw= clientes.Clientes(self)



        self.treeWidget=  QPersistentModelIndex()
   
        
        self.handlebuttons(self)


        
´´´
```

In here I´d like to use a function similar to 'clicked.connect´ to link the treewidget to another window.

Maybe a way to map the whole treeview and identify whitch child is click to execute the function.

Gett is the function that opens the new window.´´´

```
´´´
    
    def handlebuttons(self,WhatsThisClicked):
        
        if WhatsThisClicked==self.treeWidget.child(0,0):
            self.gett()

    def gett(self):
        self.clientesw= clientes.Clientes(self)
        self.clientesw.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
 
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

´´´
Thank you
```

Comment: Your code is quite nonsensical: for instance, you cannot create a QPersistentModelIndex without a valid QModelIndex argument, and calling `self.handlebuttons(self)` doesn't make any sense, especially considering that `WhatsThisClicked` would be `self` (so, the main window). That said, just use the [signals the widget provides](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#signals), starting with `itemClicked`.

Comment: Thank you fot your comments, but I am sorry, I am new in this, could you specify how could I make an item like for example Parent (0). child(0) able to connect with a new window using the function ```itemClicked´´´.

Comment: `itemClicked` is not a function, it's a signal. If you don't know what that means, I strongly suggest you to do some research on the subject. Besides, the link above refers to QTreeWidget, not QTreeWidgetItem (which is not a QObject and does not have any signal).